# What android apps are these?

Tags: applications, system

I currently use a TCL A1 (A501DL) running Android Version 8.1.0.

I went to check my Wi-Fi data usage. I scrolled down and seen all these apps! There are 9 of them. I've never seen them before and when I click them there is no app information.

I checked all 44 apps I have, and it doesn't show any of these and it doesn't appear to be feeding off my battery data I already checked that. What's going on? Am I being hacked?? I don't use the cell data on this phone. I just use it for Wi-Fi. Somebody please help me! I'm kind of worried about my privacy now.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those could either be OEM bloat of it's a malware.

Comment: You said it's a OEM bloat?? What's that exactly? And you said it's malware or it is malware if it's not a OEM bloat

Comment: Do you know if these services existed when you first bought your device? Did you check data usage before?

Comment: Yeah I have never seen these before at all